# Which paypal SDK/API to use to send credit card payments to email address?

Tags: php, api, paypal, credit-card

Is there anyway to do the following using the Paypal APIs in PHP? I can't seem to find exactly what I need.

- We are a merchant - we have several businesses who list their goods on our website.
- Customers will need to pay for these goods using a credit/debit card. We don't want to force Paypal use/registration - in fact, we don't really want the customer to interact with Paypal at all.
- We'd like to create a payment form where they enter their credit card details - we would then use the API to pay this directly to the business' Paypal account using their email address.

Using the REST API I've been able to do this to an extent - the only problem with this is that it doesn't seem dynamic i.e. I can't set the Payee email address to receive the payment - it's linked to my account via the ClientID and ClientSecret. Obviously this is not what I need -  I want to pay into the account of the owner of the goods, not mine.

I've seen 'Guest Payments' mentioned but that seems to require the user being redirected to Paypal - something I'd rather avoid.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the REST API is quite ready for what you're doing.  The Classic API will handle it with no problem, though.

If you don't want any interaction with PayPal at all then you'll need to use [Payments Pro](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/paypal-payments-pro/), which allows you to tie credit card payments directly into your own forms via HTTP request/response with PayPal (no redirect or iframe).

Each business would need to be signed up with their own Payments Pro account, and then they would Grant API Permissions through their PayPal account profile for your app to make API calls on their behalf.  Once they've done that, you just pass their email address or PayPal merchant ID into the SUBJECT parameter of API requests and it will use their account accordingly even though you're still using your own API credentials.

The [Permissions API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/) allows you to automate this and tie the grant permissions step directly into your app so business owners can do that quickly and easily from within their profile or during signup with your site.  This works with auth tokens, though, as opposed to email addresses and merchant ID's.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, sounds exactly what I'm looking for. The only downside is that each business will need their own Payments Pro account - am I correct in thinking this type of account has a monthly fee?

Comment: Yes, the full Payments Pro solution will cost each of them $30/mo.